# Why my custom select view filter is not working?

Tags: 8, views, hooks

I have a publication content type, each publication can have one or more authors. I'm trying to add a custom select list filter depending on the author, so far i managed to make it appear in the view with all the author values from the nodes, but when i select the author in the filter no results appear even if the publication author matches the one in the filter.

The filter is already created in the view, and i just edited it using hooks.

```
function module_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form,$form_id,&$form_state){
    if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-publications-view-block-1'){

       //This one works fine
       $form['field_publication_year_value']['#type'] = 'select';
       $form['field_publication_year_value']['#size'] = 'null';
       $form['field_publication_year_value']['#options'] = returnArrayOfYears();
       $form['field_publication_year_value']['#validated'] = true;

       //Shows no results
       $form['field_publication_author_value']['#type'] = 'select';
       $form['field_publication_author_value']['#size'] = 'null';
       $form['field_publication_author_value']['#options'] = returnAllAuthorsNames();
       $form['field_publication_author_value']['#validated'] = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the years since the first publication from now
 * inside an array
 * 
 */
function returnArrayOfYears(){

    $startingYear = 2011;
    $currentYear = intval(date('Y'));
    $yearArr = [];

    for($startingYear; $startingYear < $currentYear; $startingYear++){
        array_push($yearArr,[$startingYear => $startingYear]);
    }
    return $yearArr;
}


/**
 * Gets all the names from the authors from the nodes 
 * and returns them inside an array
 * 
 */
function returnAllAuthorsNames(){

    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','publication')->execute();
    $nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $authors = [];

    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $node_authors = $node->get('field_publication_author')->getValue();

        foreach($node_authors as $author){
            array_push($authors,$author['value']);
        }
    }
    return $authors;
}
```

The authors field is a multiple value one, maybe that is causing the problem? Also the filter is set as a regex expression.

[image]

Any clue to why this is not working? All the author names appear fine in the view but when i select one the result is nothing.

Comment: Are the keys of your authors list ok ? From what I see `array_push($authors, $author["value"]);` will return something like [0 => authorID1, 1 => authorID2, ...] where you need to have [authorID1 => authorName1, authorID2 => authorName2, ...] instead.

Comment: @misterdidi In the view the select filter appears with the correct values, with the names of the authors not the id's so i think the keys are right. I really don't now why it doesn't work, in the filter you can see the name and it's the same as the field in the view, but the regex comparation doesn't work